# Call method in xamarin.ios from PCL project

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS project in `AppDelegate` class I have method:

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

    Hub.UnregisterAllAsync (deviceToken, (error) => {
        if (error != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
            return;
        }

        NSSet tags = null; // create tags if you want
        Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
            if (errorCallback != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
        });
    });
}
```

How I can call it from my PCL project?

Comment: either use DependencyServer or MessagingCenter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Create an interface in your PCL project:

```c
namespace YourNamespace.Interfaces
{
    public interface IRemoteNotifications
    {
        void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken);
    }
}
```

b) Create a class that will implement this interface in your iOS project, remeber to decorate the class with the required attributes:

```c
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(RemoteNotifications))]
namespace YourNamespace.iOS.DependencyService
{
    public class RemoteNotifications : IRemoteNotifications
    {
        public void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            // Place your custom logic here
        }
    }
}
```

c) Call your custom implementation from the PCL project using Dependency Service to locate the Interface implementation.

```c
DependencyService.Get<IRemoteNotifications>().RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(application, deviceToken);
```

d) Execute your logic.

That is all you need.

Comment: thank you for answer, but these types `UIApplication` and `NSdata` are not available in PCL or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are right they do not exist in PCL so you will need to look for another way to obtain that data without sending it from the PCL. In my answer, I was just showing you how to call a method from the native project which was your original question. However, now you need to check how to obtain those values from the native project. For instance, you can obtain them in the AppDelegate, then, store them in a static variable and then call them from your method.